# Joining point features to polygon features?

Tags: arcgis-pro

I have a point feature shapefile and a polygon feature shapefile. I would like to join them and have a single output file where I can see which points are in the polygons.

Can I do that?

Comment: Explore the spatial join tool.

Comment: Spatial Join is temporary. Identity creates a new dataset with field from both sources.

Comment: I’d use Intersect.

Comment: :) Spatial Join, Identity or Intersect, such choice!